# data loss in local Storage on page reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YILTI.png)I am trying to save my data to local Storage and it succeeds, but when reloading the page it disappears, is there any way to handle it, I am new and need help, thanks a lot

[image: Code Sample]

Comment: My only assumption is that the useEffect is getting triggered initially with empty `cartItems` when you reload the page. You can try by adding an If condition block which checks if cartItems has any values like `cartItems != null` and then add something `localStorage`

Comment: Please make sure that your not using `localStorage.clear();` in your code (or other pages of your project) .

Comment: How are you reading your data back from `localStorage`?

Comment: thank you very much, i am dealing with localStorage in App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your code, you lose your storage since the effect will override values and set it empty, and this happens since you do not validate if cart items are empty or not.

In react hook in your example, the first call will be with init value (maybe it's null), and if it's not fetching data again so that it will be removed.

Try to add this to your effect (as an example):

```
if(cartsItem.length > 0){
  // set local storage.
}
```

Another thing, you need to make sure if this is not fully coded if there's any place was remove local storage and its important.

Comment: thanks so much, i have prevented the data deletion in localStorage, but it lost render data to the screen, can you explain it for me?